# Android Studio and Kotlin - Set breakpoint at runtime in a suspend function doesn't work

Tags: android, kotlin, debugging, breakpoints, suspend

In my Android app developed in Kotlin I'm not able to make the debugger stop on breakpoints set at runtime in a Dynamic Feature with suspend functions. If I set the breakpoint before launching the app it works, but when I try to set the same breakpoint at runtime it doesn't, the debugger simply keeps skipping the breakpoints. I also checked "suspend all" in the breakpoint options to no avail, the debugger still skips the breakpoint. A very annoying situation because every time I need to pause the execution at a specific line in a suspend function, I must first stop the app, then set the breakpoint and then restart the app. Only in that case it works. On the contrary if I set a breakpoint in a no-suspend function, it works at runtime too. Any idea?

Comment: Jetbrains is aware of this issue. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-27810